# getting an error in ionic3 when taking build

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

try to run ionic cordova build android i'm getting **[WARN] Error occurred during command execution from a CLI plugin (@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova). Your plugins may be out of date.
TypeError: env.runcmd is not a function**  my ionic info is

@ionic/cli-utils : 1.2.0
Cordova CLI      : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
Ionic CLI        : 3.2.0

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.2
Cordova Platforms  : android 8.1.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.5
```

System:

```
Node       : v8.11.1
OS         : macOS
Xcode      : Xcode 11.6 Build version 11E708 
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
```

Comment: update your Ionic CLI.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @NajamUsSaqib  i did it now it's working fine.